# Good book on the history of fabrication?

Tags: chip

*Crystal Fire* is a great book about the development of the transistor, but much less so for the IC side of things. What is the equivalent for ICs, and especially microprocessor development?

I'm interested in the seminal steps in fabrication improvements that led to the changes in chip design. For instance, I know the 6502 was able to hit its price point because it moved to NMOS and made use of a new stepper technology, Micralign.

Can anyone recommend a good book that gets into this level of detail during the major steps from the first ICs through to, say, the CMOS era of the early 1980s?

Comment: VLSI - see this Wiki page on [Carver Mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carver_Mead)

Answer (score 5):

Not a book, but the Computer History Museum has videos in their online collection of the oral histories given by many people associated with the development of many early silicon IC (and earlier!) products.

The IEEE history center also has some great online resources:
https://www.ieee.org/about/history-center/index.html